# javascript variable in string

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling with this Javascript:

```
 width = screen.width * .75;
 height = screen.height * .75;

$(".colorbox").colorbox({
  width:"800px", 
  height:"600px", 
  iframe:true, 
  scrolling:false});
```

I am trying to put the values of width and height into the 800 and 600 spots, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty straightforward to fix:

```
var width = screen.width * .75; 
var height = screen.height * .75;

$(".colorbox").colorbox({
  width: width, 
  height: height, 
  iframe: true, 
  scrolling: false});
```

(Just a side note, put `var` before your variable declarations, or else they will become global, perhaps unintentionally).

Comment: +1 but pretty please suggest the use of `var` and that globals are bad, etc. ;)

Comment: Or just `width: screen.width * 0.75;` etc. to avoid the possibility of globals completely.

Answer (score 1):

Colorbox actually supports specifying the widths as integers or with a unit..

So,

```
$(".colobox").colorbox({
  "width": width,
  "height": height
});
```